# Saving my head.php without BOM destroys my mutated vowels

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I think I have a serious problem concerning the collation of my page in connection with the BOM. After checking my page with the w3 validator I saw that at the beginning of my head.php a BOM is showing up. Problem is, after I saved my head.php in utf-8 without BOM (before it was just utf-8) all input on all pages gets messed up. More specifically the mutated vowels (äöüß etc) are now shown as Ã¶, Ã¤, ÃŸ and so on. How is that possible? I have actually set and saved everything to utf-8.

I have saved every page of my website as utf-8 without BOM.

The collation of my server manager on the FTP-Server is set to "utf-8".
The charset of my head.php is set to utf-8:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

The connection to my DB via PDO is set in utf-8:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8';
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
    );
```

The collation of my databank and the data-table is set to `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Does someone have an idea what I can do here or where I can start looking for the problem?

EDIT: I just cannot find a mistake here. Created a simple .php file with plain text and set it the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and saved it with "utf-8 without BOM". Also checked on the text with

```
<?php echo "encoding:". mb_detect_encoding("öäü"); ?>
```

and it says: UTF-8. But still, mutated vowels are like Ã¶, Ã¤, ÃŸ... I really don't know what to do here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Side note: if you're using HTML5, your `meta` can be simplified to `<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: @domdom thanks for your help. Plz check my edit. I just cannot find what I am missing here. According to web-sniffer.net it is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1` though I have no idea how this can still happen.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to my .htaccess:

`AddDefaultCharset utf-8`

and now the HTTP-Header responds correctly `utf-8`. Finally the mutated vowels show up like they should.